# Why does my stringstream get filled with garbage after tryng to insert the contents into a vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector, stringstream

Consider the code:

```
void someFunc {
    std::stringstream value;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mapLayerCollision;
    int row = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < gid_list.length(); i++) {
        if(gid_list[i] == ',') {
            value.str("");
            int j = 1;
            while (gid_list[i-j] != ',' and i - j > 0) {
                std::cout << gid_list[i-j] << " | ";
                j++;
                std::cout << gid_list[i-j] << std::endl;
            }
            j--;
            value.str("");
            std::cout << "j: " << j << std::endl;
            while (j > 0) {
                std::cout << "Inserting: " << gid_list[i-j] << std::endl;
                value << gid_list[i-j];
                std::cout << "Value AFTER: " << value.str() << std::endl;
                j--;
            }
            std::cout << "Putting into vector: " << std::stoi(value.str()) << std::endl;
            //mapLayerCollision[row].push_back(std::stoi(value.str()));
            value.str("");
        }
        
        else if(gid_list[i] == '\n') {
            value.str("");
            int j = 1;
            while (gid_list[i-j] != ',') {
                j++;
            }
            j--;
            value.str("");
            while (j > 0) {
                value << gid_list[i-j];
                j--;
            }
            std::cout << "Putting into vector: " << value.str() << std::endl;
            //mapLayerCollision[row].push_back(std::stoi(value.str()));
            value.str("");
            row++;
        }
    }
}
```

The declaration of `gid_list` is: `std::string gid_list;`, and the contents are:

```
79,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,454,455,70,
274,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,195,210,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,274,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,323,338,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,387,402,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,346,0,0,0,350,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,451,466,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,410,0,0,0,414,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
338,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
402,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
338,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,195,210,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
402,0,0,0,0,195,198,199,200,210,0,0,0,0,0,0,451,466,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,387,264,264,264,402,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,451,455,456,457,466,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
274,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,259,
212,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,216,
73,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,199,200,201,199,200,201,76
```

So I have the lines of code that insert the stringstream value into the vector commented out, the values being printed are correct, but as soon as I uncomment those lines the printed values of the stringstream are garbled and seem to be filled with random stuff. I know that stringstreams can be finicky, but the most confusing part is that the values are printed BEFORE being added to the vector. Question: Why is the stringstream value changing when a line of code is modified AFTER it, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to replace `[row]` with `.at(row)` and run - this will help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Clearly you have UB somewhere in your code. All the vector accesses is where I would start looking.

Comment: @john UB? What's that?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour. When your program behaves weird that's generally what you have. One cause is out of bounds array, string or vector access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that `stringstream` can be finicky

It is not finicky, you use it improperly.

All your code can be simpler

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mapLayerCollision;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(cin, line)) {
  mapLayerCollision.emplace_back();  // This fixes your issue you have asked
  std::istringstream values(line);
  int n;
  while (values >> n) {
    mapLayerCollision.back().push_back(n);
    char c;
    if ((values >> c) && c != ',') {
      // bad content
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The issue in your code is `mapLayerCollision[row]` that attempts to access `row`th element of the empty vector.

Comment: `cin.getline(line)` needs to be `getline(cin, line)`, and `mapLayerCollision.push_back()` needs to be either `mapLayerCollision.push_back(std::vector<int>{})` or `mapLayerCollision.emplace_back()`. Also, `std::istringstream` *should* be used instead of `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Thank you! Updated. I wrote it from memory.

Comment: What does `emblace_back` do?

Comment: [std::vector::emplace_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) - Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is constructed from the arguments passed to. No arguments are passed - the default element's constructor is used. `mapLayerCollision.emplace_back()` is same as `mapLayerCollision.push_back(std::vector<int>{})`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by adding `this->mapLayerCollision.emplace_back();` to every `while` loop. Revised code:

```
void someFunc {
    std::stringstream value;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mapLayerCollision;
    int row = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < gid_list.length(); i++) {
        if(gid_list[i] == ',') {
            value.str("");
            int j = 1;
            while (gid_list[i-j] != ',' and i - j > 0) {
                this->mapLayerCollision.emplace_back();
                j++;
            }
            j--;
            value.str("");
            std::cout << "j: " << j << std::endl;
            while (j > 0) {
                this->mapLayerCollision.emplace_back();
                value << gid_list[i-j];
                j--;
            }
            mapLayerCollision[row].push_back(std::stoi(value.str()));
            value.str("");
        }
        
        else if(gid_list[i] == '\n') {
            value.str("");
            int j = 1;
            while (gid_list[i-j] != ',') {
                j++;
            }
            j--;
            value.str("");
            while (j > 0) {
                this->mapLayerCollision.emplace_back();
                value << gid_list[i-j];
                j--;
            }
            value.str("");
            row++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @273K I'm still marking your answer as the answer, I'm just putting my revision of my code. I'm aware it's not very good code.